# Overlapping box-shadows on adjacent active buttons in checkbox button group

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, box-shadow

When toggling (active) adjacent buttons in the example provided in https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons the box-shadow overlaps from one button to another.

[image]

The box shadow for each button is simply:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(134,142,150,.5)
```

Is there a way that we could prevent this? It looks broken, specially when more than two buttons are adjacent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the box shadows to overlap into one consistent color, you can do the following:

`box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgb(194,198,202)`

If you do not want the box shadows to overlap, you can the the following:

```
.btn-secondary:not([disabled]):not(.disabled).active {
  box-shadow:
    0 -0.2rem rgba(134,142,150,.5),
    0 0.2rem rgba(134,142,150,.5);   
}

label.btn-secondary:not([disabled]):not(.disabled).active:first-child {
  box-shadow:
    -0.2rem 0 0  0.2rem rgba(134,142,150,.5);   
}

label.btn-secondary:not([disabled]):not(.disabled).active:last-child {
  box-shadow:
    0.2rem 0 0  0.2rem rgba(134,142,150,.5);  
}
```

Comment: Doing that shows Checkbox2's box-shadow on top of Checkbox3

Comment: Sorry for the double comment, I thought I would show what I meant: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KyabMm.

Comment: So you want a box-shadow that does not overlap neighboring buttons?
This only covers one of the css rules, but I think you'll be able to understand what I did.

https://codepen.io/danielmayorga/pen/POWVKO

Comment: This is great, I can take it from here and apply it to the rest of the rules. Didn't know you could add two distinct box-shadows to an element. Thanks again for taking the time.